# Передача массива частями через js (jquery)

Tags: массивы, jquery, ajax, json, get

Есть список пользователей(список контактов), периодический требуется отправлять ихние id на сервер для поверки кто в сети и еще много чего, проблема в том что передавать большое значение не получается, если только через POST + ajax, но это для тех кто любить легкий выход.
Вопрос: как отправить массив "vals" частями, к примеру по 10 ключей за раз ?

```
function updateMessFriends() {
  vals = [];
  $("div[class^='friends']").each(function () {
    n = $('#' + this.id).data('options');
    vals.push({
      id: n.id,
      time: n.time
    })
  }); 
  $.getJSON("node.php", {
    stuff: vals
  }, function (json) {
    $.each(json, function (i, events) {
      alert(events.time)
    })
  })
}
setInterval('updateMessFriends()', 2000)
```

**Какой на ваш взгляд более приемлемое решение, учитывая что есть список юзеров и надо собрать и отправить ихние id, time потом получить id, time и обновить у каждого time ?**

Comment: А почему не обновлять весь список контактов? о_О

Comment: Список контактов статичен, или может меняться на ходу после загрузки страницы? *ой, некропост из 2012, не заметил.

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateMessFriends() {
  vals = [];
  var counter = 0;
  $("div[class^='friends']").each(function () {
    n = $('#' + this.id).data('options');
    vals.push({
      id: n.id,
      time: n.time
    })

  if(counter >= 10) {
     $.getJSON("node.php", {
       stuff: vals
     }, function (json) {
       $.each(json, function (i, events) {
         alert(events.time)
       })
     });
    counter = 0;
    vals = [];
  }

  });

}
setInterval('updateMessFriends()', 2000)
```

Алсо решений мильон, а вы выбрали самое хреновое. Совет да любовь: отправлять большие данные через POST.

Comment: кстати такая штука не прокатит, если пользователей меньше 10. Опять нужен еще один костыль.

Comment: bad:

    setInterval('updateMessFriends()', 2000)

good:

    setInterval(updateMessFriends, 2000)